# LTC3300 active cell balancer - unreliable SPI communication?

Tags: spi, cell-balancing

I have been using the LTC3300 IC for a couple of years.  I always observed unreliable SPI communication.  I played with SPI timing and had the controller resend the commands until they get through... maybe it was a PCB design issue?

I have now redesigned the PCB with a faster controller and a lot of care around the SPI traces... but I cannot get SPI communication to work even at 50kHz (note: I have used SPI in many other projects and always worked flawlessly).

I have communicated with technical staff @ Analog Devices and done all the tests and measures they asked for... until they stopped responding!
Maybe we all missed something obvious (which I hope), but  **I now strongly suspect the LTC3300 to operate in different SPI modes when writing to it or reading from it**.  I will explain below what I have done that leads me to that conclusion.

**note:** all the components are purchased form authorized distributor Mouser or Digikey, so I know I am using genuine components.

**LTC3300 SPI mode:** The datasheet is quite unclear on that topic, but considering that the demo board uses a LTC6804 as SPI master and that "*The SPI master on LTC6804 supports only SPI mode 3 (CHPA = 1, CPOL = 1)*" I assume I need to use SPI mode 3... until last week when an AD engineer told me "*As I look at the timing diagram given in the datasheet, I see only one chip select transition to decide whether the clock idle is high or low. If you look at the chip select before it is pulled low (active low), the state of the clock is low (i.e. the idle state) which means the clock is idle low (i.e. CPOL=0). And similarly, the data is sampled at the rising edge which means CPHA=0.*".
Using SPI mode 0 has not fixed the problem!

**SPI timing:**  So I looked a bit closer at the SPI signals with a read command (0xAA) and expected data of 0x0C06
[image]
[image]

- MOSI: LTC3300 properly registers the commands and data/CRC sent by the controller (that is confirmed when I send a read-back command and the LTC3300 returns something other than 0's on MISO)
- MISO: we see that the LTC3300 shifts MISO data on the rising edge of the clock when with SPI mode 0 (and mode 3) it should do it on the falling edge (note that 0x180C shifted one bit to the right is 0x0C06 - what we expect).

**Additional notes:**

- the scope probes are connected about 25mm from the LTC3300
- MISO shift 0->1 happens 210 nanoseconds after the clock rising edge
- MISO shift 1->0 happens 140 nanoseconds after the clock rising edge
- As I use a 3V3->5V level translator, so I rigged a 5V controller without level translator = the results are the same
- I did the same measures at 50kHz and 500khz and the MISO data shift always happen the same delay after the rising edge of the clock

Analog Devices engineer only wants to talk about parasitic impedance that, in their opinion, is the cause for what I observe.

**My questions are:**

1. The recorded traces are reasonably square in relation to the clock period - therefore can we conclude that parasitic impedance does not distort or delay the signal in a significant way in relation to the clock frequency?
2. What kind of passive circuitry (or other phenomenon) could **shift forward** MISO by half a clock period? (the first MISO shift 1->0 happens on the eighth rising edge of the clock when it should happen on the eighth falling edge)
3. Any advice on possible next steps considering that I did not get a response from AD in the last 7 days?

Thank you for any suggestion to either find / fix the cause or deal with the situation.

Comment: I don't think any parasitic impedance would cause this kind of thing - it is definitely related to the digital logic.

Comment: However I am also not sure what the problem is exactly. It looks like MISO is *always* changing on the rising clock edge.

Comment: Datasheet says SDI must be valid 10ns before and 250ns after the rising clock edge (so change on falling clock edge) and SDO is valid 250ns after the falling clock edge (so sample on rising clock edge). This is indeed annoying if you are trying to interface with an SPI peripheral which expects to sample and output things to happen on the same clock edge. And the marketing part of the datasheet says SPI-compatible, which I agree this probably isn't.

Comment: Have you considered simply bit-banging it instead of trying to use the microcontroller's SPI peripheral?

Comment: If the chip is doing what the datasheet says, there is no problem for Analog Devices, except for possibly giving them feedback to design their next chip differently.

Comment: Thanks @user253751 for your comments and suggestions.  I am not sure I understand your third comment as according to the timing diagrams on the datasheet, both SDO and SDI should change on the falling edge and be sampled on the rising edge of the clock.
But in fact SDO does change on the rising clock edge.  So the chip does not do what the datasheet says

Comment: I have managed to read some of the data on SDO by changing the SPI mode after sending the read command on SDI (first 8 clock beats) and before restarting the clock to get SDO (the following 16 clock beats).  The problem is that I loose the first bit of SDO as it should be read on the falling edge of the 8th clock beat!

Comment: I may have been wrong about the timing diagram.

Comment: but if you check how the timing is defined on [page 15](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC3300-1.pdf) it shows SDI referenced to the rising edge and SDO referenced to the falling edge. However, since t2 is longer than half the clock period in the example, SDI changes after the falling edge in the example.

Comment: It sounds normal to reference SDI to the rising edge with minimum values as this is the edge used by the LTC3300 to sample SDI.  SDO is referenced to the falling edge with maximum value as this is the change edge that is controlled by the LTC3300.  Thank you for input as I can now go back to ADI being confident that I did not do a stupid mistake or oversight.   I will post here any outcome...